# Android Studio Dependency Search

Tags: android, dependency-management

Is there any plugin in android studio to search for dependencies. Like if i wanted to include retrofit library, I just have to search the keyword 'retrofit'  and it will be added to the build.gradle

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I add a library project to Android Studio?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16588064/how-do-i-add-a-library-project-to-android-studio)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Go to open module setting of project. Click on + button on right side, and search retrofit by clicking search button.

Answer (score 8):

Open Module Settings by right clicking on `app` and selecting `Open Module Settings`:

[image]

A dialog window will appear titled with `Project Structure`. Select `Dependencies` Tab and click on `+` icon shown in the right toolbar.

Select

1. `Library Dependency` if you want to add dependencies from web.
2. `File Dependency` if you want to add jar file dependencies residue in your project `lib` folder.
3. `Module Dependency` if you want to add a project module dependencies.

[image]

I selected Library Dependencies and Searched for `volley`, results are:

[image]

Hope this will help you enough.

Comment: How do I add a local .so dependency file... why is it just from the web?

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

Project Structure > Dependencies Tab > Add module dependency

Answer (score 0):

right click on your project>open module setting >> select dependency tab from right window  >> click plus from bottom toolbar >> select library dependency> in the dialog enter your search text > click ok

Answer (score 0):

I don't think that kind of plugin exists but check out this link.This is something similar of what you are looking.

http://gradleplease.appspot.com/#appcompat

You have to type the name of the library and it will give you the gradle dependancy link which you have to put in your gradle file.
Try this